# Why are my perf counter logs disappearing after the scheduled run time?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, perfmon

I've setup a user defined data collector set in perfmon on Windows Server 2008 R2 Std. I have it set to run for 24hrs. When it is running, I can see the files it is creating in the output path. However, after the 24hrs are up, it stops collecting (good) and then all the files in the output path disappear (bad!).

Has anyone seen this before? What is up?

Comment: Yesterday, I had set the output path as the drive which contained the website, sql server database and users' file uploads. The nightmare started when the files and folders in the drive started disappearing in front of my eyes. I invite you all to my funeral service today at 5pm

Comment: I'm watching the exact same thing happen on a 2 hour job on a Windows 10 1709 machine... it is just a simple data collection created from the System>System Performance template with the stop condition changed to 2 hours... extremely frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at the Data Manager rules? Right click on your custom set and click Data Manager. Is your resource policy set to delete the largest? Also what's the maximum size set to? I would assume that a 24 hour collector is going to consume a good portion of the disk its being written to and if it's not setup correctly it may be deleting itself.

Comment: It is set to delete largest, maximum size set to 1024 MB. The perf logs CSV file was < 32MB after a 24hr run though. The minimum free disk space setting of 200MB is no where near being a problem. Also it is set to "Apply policy before the data collector set starts", wouldn't that mean it would delete stuff BEFORE running, instead of after a run?

Comment: This answer fixed my problem. I unchecked "Maximum root path size" and the output no longer deleted when the run was completed.